# getting first 5 digits of a database stored number in the query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with a table and there is field in my table which stores raw `time()` function value as date.

I want to get rows with today date from this table .

So i figure out when `time()` func returns a 10 digit number like `1316352184` the first 5 digits  are for year , month , day which i need for getting today's date  and the rest is for hour minute Second which i dont need

So i get today without hour and... like

```
$t = time();
$t = $t /100000;
$today =(int)$t;
```

Now i need to get rows with today date from the table but i'm not sure how to do that.

How can i get first 5 digits of stored date in database in my query to compare it with $date?

Something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ((int)date/100000) as date = $today ;
```

Comment: Are you getting mixed up with UNIX timestamps?

Comment: Can you please clarify? Is this agains MySQL database?

Comment: yes it's mysql and it stores raw time() function value as date

Comment: Do not `reinvent the wheel`, use MySQL built-in date / time functions ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table
where from_unixtime(unix_timestamp_field,'%Y-%m-%d') = curdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date(date) = date(NOW());
```

Comment: Does `MySQL` `date` function accept timestamp value argument?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a UNIX timestamp. The number of seconds since January 1st, 1970.

You can use date() and mktime() to work out what todays timestamp is, then do date > the timestamp. If that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use the `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` data type for your column so you can use MySQL's date functions.